# Django autocomplete search by tag and render Tag List

Tags: ajax, django, search, autocomplete, django-taggit

ive searched through the autocomplete packages to realize my autocomplete search. But all what ive found is autocompleting one word. I need a list of words- not just one.

It should behave like here on stack tag input. user start typing-select the tag if there is set one. Insert as many tags as he need and when hes finished the whole list of tags should render a List filtered by those tags with taggit.

But how to realize the search for many tags? Autocomplete only works for one?! or did i understand something badly wrong?

Comment: you can to it with jquery autocomplete, making an Ajax request to Django: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: looks pretty. and how insert a list of items?!? like: java javascript erlang

Comment: on successfull ajax response, you will have the JSON list of retrieved elements. Inserrt them with jQuery for example in you drop down

Comment: okay understand. and howto ajax on the backend?? thirdpartymodule or REST and js framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI part:

```
$("#id_of_your_input").keypress(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: $(this).data('url'), ## or hard code it: source: '/api/...'
        minLength: 2,
        delay:300,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#id_of_your_drop_down').val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```

The view which handles your `$(this).data('url')`:

```
import json

NUMBER_OF_RESULTS = 5

def view_for_your_api(request):
    if not request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponse('false')
    results = model.objects.all()[:NUMBER_OF_RESULTS]
    data = json.dumps([{'label': r.name, 'value': r.name} for r in results])
    return HttpResponse(data, 'application/json')
```

I assumed you have `r.name` in your model. Replace it with your field or your neccessities

Answer (score 0):

This is a good idea  "Get multiple autocomplete suggestions".

Here is how autocomplete works. 
For example whenever you type something in a text box the AJAX runs and returns particular result for that specific texts.

To get multiple autocompletes..

If you want to do that multiple autocomplete you need to save multiple data or tags in a column according to repeated occurances. or make a "*one to many relationship" in the database and return all those values.

Comment: yes it seems pretty that i have in mind. setting a list of objects by autocomplete(so user cant type a keyword which isn't set). On enter add it to the list and when finished load a view filtered by those keywords. Wouldn it be better to make on a frontend js_framework like ember and some Restful api? Thought about tastypie and ember? wouldnt it be the better idea instead of jquery?